# Visual Studio Compile Warning: Using system operator==/!= for GUIDs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, driver

I am trying to convert a Windows driver project from using the DDK build system and Makefiles into a project that can be compiled from within Visual Studio 2012.

I've followed [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31865/How-to-Configure-Visual-Studio-2008-for-Compiling) for setting up the project options, but I am getting this warning when I try to compile:

```
warning : Using system operator==/!= for GUIDs
```

I guess there is a project configuration flag that I can set that will fix this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why has the question been down voted twice?

Comment: I see only one downvote (I have enough rep to see the details). Does not matter, your question does not deserve any downvote. I'll bring you back to zero with my upvote - which I would have given you anyways.

Comment: Don't forget to award the bounty (it is not done automatically!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because using ==/!= on a GUID may not yield correct results, since the GUID is a non-trivial structure type.

When compiled as C++, `guiddef.h` implements ==/!= using this: [IsEqualCLSID on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In your case, the problem is that the DDK header is unable to implement the C++ operator overloads for ==/!= GUIDs. It looks to me like this would happen because `guiddef.h` is being included prior to including the DDK headers. Apparently `guiddef.h` and the DDK don't agree on how the ==/!= operators should be implemented, and so the DDK issues a warning.

So my guess is that all you really need to do is revisit the includes order. Also, I can't verify it since I don't have VS 2012 handy, but its quite possible that this warning itself is the only thing 'new' and that the actual behavior of the program may be unchanged from VS2008. VS2008 may very well have done the same thing but failed to issue a warniner to alert the programmer. In which case, if it worked in the old compiler then it probably should work in the new one too.

Comment: I do not get this warning when compiling with the DDK build system. I do not want to change the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I no longer think the code is wrong (well it might be), but rather that the warning is new in VS 2012 and that the actual code generated for GUID compares is probably unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, but I only include one main header from the DDK. Perhaps disabling the warning is the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/include/ddk/kcom.h?revision=26218&view=markup&pathrev=26218), that warning is given by:

```
#if defined(_SYS_GUID_OPERATOR_EQ_)
#define _GUID_OPERATORS_
#pragma message("WARNING: Using system operator==/!= for GUIDs")
#endif
```

And it looks like that can be disabled by defining `_NO_SYS_GUID_OPERATOR_EQ_`. So try a compiler option of `/D_NO_SYS_GUID_OPERATOR_EQ_`.

However, I don't recommend doing something unless you know *why* you're doing it. Perhaps you're supposed to supply your own overloads?

Comment: @infact You hadn't explained that at the time of posting. Nonetheless, that file seems to have some kind of compatibility with the Windows DDK. So I expect the same is still true.